# Hint to clear your browser's cache when script fails

Tags: qooxdoo

When I upgrade my qooxdoo application with new features sometimes it causes the browser to fail when loading the script/application.js file and displays a blank screen.  Is there an easy way to check if that script failed and display a message to the user that they may need to clear their browsers cache?

Answer (score 1):

Did you get any warnings in your browser console?

Every time you use a new class you haven't used before, you have to run (`./generate.py source`). If you find that cumbersome read more about the `source-all` and `source-hybrid` jobs:

- v2.1.1: http://manual.qooxdoo.org/2.1.1/pages/tool/generator/generator_default_jobs.html#source
- v3.0 (not yet released): http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0/pages/tool/generator/default_jobs_actions.html#source

Comment: It's not necessarily me, but the user's who come to the site get the error. I'm trying to provide a nice way for them to know when they need to clear their cache. It's a fairly in depth page, so caching is preferable until a new release comes out.